# Is there a way to dissect a sql query to get table names, columns, join conditions and filter conditions

Tags: sql, metadata

I am looking for a solution/approach to derive the table names, column names of the tables, joins between tables and filter condition into a file. basically extract the metadata of a sql query into a file and I will be comparing this query metadata to see are there any other such similar queries (duplicate queries) using the same tables, columns, join types etc. I am seeking the suggestions (any existing libraries) from this forum and really appreciate the help.

Input Query

```
SELECT T1.COL1, T1.COL2, T2.COL1
FROM TABLE T1 LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL4
INNER JOIN T3
ON T1.COL1 = T3.COL2
WHERE T1.COL1 > 10
  AND T3.Col3 IS NULL
```

Output:

```
Tables: T1, T2, T3
Columns: T1.COL1,T1.COL2,T2.COL1
Joins: T1-->T2, T1-->T3 (correlation between tables)
Filter: T1.COL1 > 10, T3.COL3 IS NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried so far?  what is the OS where SQL is present ?

Comment: Hi..The SQL is present in Redshift. I am planning to use jsqlparser to read the metadata of the transformation  query. However I am looking for a process to read the temp tables and inner sub queries to get the complete metadata. Can you please suggest the direction/approach to tackle the problem. My requirement is to find the metadata details like tables, columns, filter conditions, column transformations from a extract sql query